# keyup is not working in bootstrap-select leave search using jQuery

Tags: bootstrap-select

This is my code, and I want to catch **changing in search input field**, but jQuery "keyup" is not working. And I'm using Angular to manipulate my data. I tried to add default text input to my page, and everything worked fine.`enter code here`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap-select live search</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            //angular stuff
            var app = angular.module('app', []);

            app.service('service', function(){
                this.getCities = function (){
                    return ["Аксаковщина д. Минская обл., Минский р-н, Горанский с/с",
            "Андреевщина д. Витебская обл., Оршанский р-н, Андреевщинский с/с",
            "Антоновка д. Гомельская обл., Калинковичский р-н, Горбовичский с/с",
            "Антоново д. Брестская обл., Барановичский р-н, Колпеницкий с/с"];
                };
            });

            app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, service){
                $scope.cities = service.getCities();
            });

            //jquery stuff
            $(document).ready(function (){
               $('input').on('keyup', function() { 
                    alert('keyup is fired!!!');
                });
            });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body  ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <div id="destinationFrom">
            <select id="selectDestinationFrom" class="selectpicker" data-live-search-style="startsWith" data-live-search="true">
                <option ng-repeat="city in cities track by $index">{{city}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="text"/>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, As we know jquery is updating day by day, So its good to use the latest version to avoid these type of errors. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use these css and js.You are using older version of css and js.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
```